# Finding a transformation given a product of 2 transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $S,T:\Bbb R^3 \rightarrow \Bbb R^3$ be a linear transformation and let $B = \{(1,1,1),(0,1,1),(0,0,1) \}$

Let $[S]_B = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

$$[T\cdot S]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I need to find $[T]_B$ and calculate $T(1,1,1)$ and $T(0,1,1)$.

Now first I said that I could separate $[T\cdot S]_B$ into $[T]_B [S]_B$ so I could write:

$$[T]_B\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

I got stuck here, don't know if I'm doing the right thing since I haven't used the info about the vectors of basis $B$.

Could someone please guide me what is the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the right thing. You will only use the basis $B$ if you want to write something like $$T(x,y,z) = (T_1(x,y,z),T_2(x,y,z),T_3(x,y,z))$$in the end. But note, though, that the first column of $[T]_B$ is $T(1,1,1)$, the second column is $T(0,1,1)$, etc.

In general, given $T : V_2 \to V_3$ and $S:V_1 \to V_2$, we have: $$[T \circ S]_{B_1,B_3} = [T]_{B_2, B_3}[S]_{B_1,B_2},$$where $B_1,B_2,B_3$ are bases for the vector spaces $V_1,V_2,V_3$. Our case is nice: $V_1 = V_2 = V_3 = \Bbb R^3$ and $B_1=B_2=B_3 = B$.

Comment: So, how do I compute the columns of $[T]_E$?

Comment: Multiply both sides of your last equation, on the right, by the inverse of $$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$which fortunately exists.

Comment: Excellent, I finally got $[T]_B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\end{pmatrix} $, now to compute $T(1,1,1)$ should I just multiply them? I still haven't used the basis that's why I'm suspicious.
Thanks alot

Comment: You meant $[T]_B$? If so, $T(1,1,1) = {\bf 0}$, because $[(1,1,1)]_B = (1,0,0)_B$.

Comment: One last question, by your example I understand that $(0,1,1) = (0,1,0)_B$, so is $T(0,1,1) = (1, 1, 1)^t$?

Comment: Yes, precisely.